Adding IP-based Search Functionality in OpenStack Skyline Dashboard
I've recently set up the OpenStack Skyline dashboard in a Docker environment, and I'm trying to enable search functionality by IP address within the interface. This would make it much easier to locate instances and resources based on their IPs.
In the Skyline source code, I found this code block located at /skyline-console-source/skyline-console-4.0.2.dev5/src/pages/compute/containers/Instance/index.jsx:
get searchFilters() {
    return [
      {
        label: t('Name'),
        name: 'name',
      },
      ...(this.isAdminPage
        ? [
            {
              label: t('Project Name'),
              name: 'project_name',
            },
            {
              label: t('Project ID'),
              name: 'project_id',
            },
          ]
        : []),
      ...(this.isAdminPage && !this.inHostDetailPage
        ? [
            {
              label: t('Host'),
              name: 'host',
            },
          ]
        : []),
      instanceStatusFilter,
    ];
  }

Would it be possible to modify or extend this code to include an option for searching by IP? Any guidance on how to implement this feature or suggestions for relevant plugins/modules would be greatly appreciated.
